# insert the coordinates into the markers collection where the map was clicked

Tags: google-maps, meteor

I just tried this *code*
**map.js**

```
Markers = new Mongo.Collection('markers');
Markers.allow({
'insert': function () {
 return true;
}
})
Template.map.helpers({
mapOptions: function() {
if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
return {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
zoom: 8
}; }
}
});
Template.map.onCreated(function() {
GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map){
google.maps.event.addListener(map.instance, 'click', function(event) {
Markers.insert({ lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng: event.latLng.lng() }) 
}); });
```

Got this error:

> **insert failed: Method not found**

question is why the insertion into the Marker **collection** fails

Answer (score 0):

Collection declaration is needed on both the client and the server.

Declaring Marker collection in **common folder** resolves the issue

// common code, do not put under /client or inside Meteor.is_client test

Markers = new Mongo.Collection("markers");